# Splitting sections from textarea output based on context

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I'm working on a system where comments are logged all into one big comment text box. I need to split these sections apart to make them look prettier on the front end...because right now it's horrible.

However, I seem to be having trouble grabbing the data and splitting it apart using javascript/jquery.

The data is coming out like this and it formatted like this every single time.

```
"Fri Jan 16 12:36:47 EST 2015
Entered by username - Persons name

This is the test comment

Sat Jan 17 2:16:00 EST 2015
Entered by username - Persons name

And this us another comment that could be very long and very redundant because these comments can be like that."
```

So I need to split thee into three different sections. Date, entered by and then the comment.

I've tried doing string splits, but that seems to only be splitting by words even when I try `\n` or `\s`

any help would be lovely. https://jsfiddle.net/wz5z2dzo/1/

Comment: Are the comments able to be multiple lines? Or are they always on one long line of text? Reason I'm asking is that you need something to split these up. Line breaks would be the most obvious way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote strings (either single or double) don't support literal new lines. Try using a template literal. I'm unsure why splitting by a specific token does not work for you...

Below is a solution. I split by line, remove empty lines, and then iterate by 3s.

```js
const nar = `Fri Jan 16 12:36:47 EST 2015
Entered by username - Persons name

This is the test comment

Sat Jan 17 2:16:00 EST 2015
Entered by username - Persons name

And this us another comment that could be very long and very redundant because these comments can be like that.`;

const lines = nar.split( "\n" ).filter( line => line );
const comments = [];

for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i += 3)
  comments.push( {
    date: lines[ i ],
    name: lines[ i + 1 ].split( " - " )[ 1 ],
    comment: lines[ i + 2 ]
  } );

console.log( comments );
```

This assumes a comment is only one line. It gets a bit more complicated if they do.

Comment: Thank you, I'll ply with it, because the comments can get very long